# Django template display different models fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to list fields from few models in a table in template. The models are joined by different fields as in below snippet:

models.py:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    clientID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pesel = models.CharField(max_length=11)

    @property
    def loan(self):
        return self.loan_set.all().first()

class Loan(models.Model):
    clientID = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    loanNo = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Case(models.Model):
    loanID = models.ForeignKey(Loan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    caseID = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    callForPaymentDate = models.DateField(default=None)

class Phase(models.Model):
    caseID = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phaseTypeID = models.ForeignKey(PhaseType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    courtID = models.TextField(max_length=200)

class PhaseDetail(models.Model):
    caseID = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phaseTypeID = models.ForeignKey(PhaseType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dismissalDate = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

As you see above models are connected by `ForeignKey`. How do I pass those models in a view (views.py below):

```
def index(request):
    clients = Client.objects.all()
    cases = Case.objects.all()
    phasedetails = PhaseDetail.objects.all()
    phases = Phase.objects.all()
    loans = Loan.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'erepertorium/index.html', 
                  {'clients': clients, 'cases': cases, 'phasedetails': phasedetails, 
                   'phases': phases, 'loans': loans})
```

So that I can display different models fields but matched by this `ForeignKey`?
See below html template:

```
    <table id="case_list" class="display">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Sygnatura wg Powoda</td>
            <td>Sygnatura EPU</td>
            <td>PESEL</td>
            <td>Numer pożyczki</td>
            <td>Imię i nazwisko</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        {% for c in clients %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ c.case.caseID }}</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>{{ c.pesel }}</td>
            <td>{{ c.loan.loanNo }}</td>
            <td>{{ c.firstName }}&nbsp;{{ c.lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've read some solutions about class based views etc. but some of the solution would require rebuilding whole models thing (over 200 lines of code). So before I do that I'd like to ask Community for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know two ways that you can achieve it.

First off with a `@property`:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    clientID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    @property
    def loan(self):
        return self.loan_set.all().first()
```

the template would be:

```
  <td>{{ c.loan.loanNo }}</td>
```

Or

in template, you access it via the reverse relation

```
  <td>{{ c.loan_set.all.0.loanNo }}</td>
```

> Make sure that before the `reverse relation` the instance owns the relation. with `if self.loan_set.all()`(**Model**) | `{% if c.loan_set.all %}` (**Template**)

Comment: This is inefficient with more than clients 10 on a page, and 1000 cases/loans etc in the DB, this would take a lot of time.

Comment: Add `.prefetch_related('loan_set', 'loan_set__case_set')` to the actual `Client.objects.all()` query.

Comment: @Lemayzeur, partially worked but how do I add a field from another related model? I modified my question (template): `<td>{{ c.case.caseID }}</td>`. This template needs to acutally display data from 4 different models.

Comment: Too much 'look up' with the reverse_relation, you lose in performance

Comment: What would you propose then? Side note: performance is not a key factor here, rather an easy way to search for correct data across few models.

Comment: You model structure is not good enough,  anyway, not too much data, you don't loose anything... add a `@propery`' method as well in Loan, name it case: `return self.case_set.all().first()` in template, you have access to it, with `{{c.loan.case}}`